# Почему параметры запроса не передаются в пост запрос?

Tags: python, requests

Делаю телеграм бота для продаж зарубежных подписок, начал добавлять платежный сервис payok. Захотел сделать функцию получения баланса,в документации payok написано это https://payok.io/cabinet/documentation/doc_api_balance
Написал такой код:

```
url = "https://payok.io/api/balance"

params = {
    "API_ID": 1234,
    "API_KEY": 'Мой api',

}
rs = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(rs.text)
```

Принт даёт `{"status":"error","error_code":"1","error_text":"Не указан идентификатор API; Параметр API_ID"}` хотя всё указано верно, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я покопался немного в документации и обнаружил что данные необходимо передавать в теле запроса, а не через URL-параметры. Попробуйте что-то такое:

```
url = "https://payok.io/api/balance"

data = {
    "API_ID": 1234,
    "API_KEY": 'Мой api',
}
    
rs = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(rs.text)
```